# Java: Purpose of annotations in comments?

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

What is the purpose of (what look like) annotations placed in comments? For example, I'm seeing the following comment above a method in an interface:

```
/**
 * Create saved search
 * REST: POST /lifecycles/savedsearches
 * @param controlParameters control parameters
 * @param search savedSearch object
 * @throws ProcessingException if any processing exceptions
 * @return Updated Object
 */
```

I understand the meaning of the comment, just wondering why this syntax was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These annotations are important for the *javadoc* tool. When it generates a documentation for a class/interface/enum/constructor/method if parses the content between `/**` and `*/`.

For a single piece of javadoc content, the tool generates a HTML-based documentation, which consists of several paragraphs. When it detects an annotation (e.g. `@param`) it adds the corresponding `@param` information to the paragraph about the `Parameters` of a method.

Checkout the [`String#concat(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) method, for example.

Also, take a look on the Oracle's [Javadoc home page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javadoc-137458.html)

Comment: Thanks - very clear. Will it also parse comments declared with `//`?

Comment: No. Only those that start with `/**` and end with  `*/`

Answer (score 2):

This is used when generating Javadoc. That way you can add an explanatory text for each parameter passed to the function and you can explain what's returned and what exceptions can be thrown and the Javadoc generator then adds your comments to the methods documentation in its corresponding places.

Then you can use that to generate html pages documenting your code based on these comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's used then for javadoc generation. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-jsp-135444.html

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is used if you generate Javadoc.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html